# Scheduled autoreply

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, scheduling, auto-reply

Outlook allow autoreply only for a **single** specific period. Neither creating a customized rule on purpose allows my task.

I want to set autoreply **repeatedly**, for instance each day from 16:00 to 09:00 of the day after.

[image]

This is an screenshot of the forms I can access *(please ignore the specific reply message, it refers to another case)*

Comment: Thanks for the changes, @Jhon. A warning pop-up appeared in my original message saying I cannot embed the screenshot, only link it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research and experience, it's not available in OOF settings and Outlook rules, you could only set for a period which includes the specific date and time(e.g. From 25/10/2021 12:00 to 26/10/2021).

However, you could schedule the following PowerShell Script using **[Task Scheduler](https://o365reports.com/2019/08/02/schedule-powershell-script-task-scheduler/)**, the following script is for your reference (This script is used to automatically update the OOF settings for your mailbox so that your mailbox will auto-reply emails from 16:00 today to 9:00 tomorrow.):

```
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
$username = "<Office365 Admin UPN>"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "<Password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username, $password)
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $UserCredential
$users = "<User's name>"
$external = '<External OOF message or HTML codes>'
$internal = '<Internal OOF message or HTML codes>'
Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity $users -AutoReplyState "Scheduled" -ExternalMessage $external -InternalMessage $Internal -StartTime (Get-Date -Hour 16 -Minute 0 -Second 0) -EndTime (((Get-Date -Hour 9 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddDays(1))) -ExternalAudience All
```

**Note**: Before adding the script to task scheduler, you need install **[EXO V2 module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)**  on your client. After that, some values of the above parameters also need be modified(e.g. `$username`, `$password`, `$users`, `$external`, `$internal`)

Here is an example of the above script:

```
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
$username = "ivan@company.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username, $password)
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $UserCredential
$users = "ivan"
$external = '<html> <body> <div></div> <div style="font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rg b(0,0,0)"> 1 </div> </body> </html>'
$internal = '<html> <body> <div></div> <div style="font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rg b(0,0,0)"> 1 </div> </body> </html>'
Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity $users -AutoReplyState "Scheduled" -ExternalMessage $external -InternalMessage $Internal -StartTime (Get-Date -Hour 16 -Minute 0 -Second 0) -EndTime (((Get-Date -Hour 9 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddDays(1))) -ExternalAudience All
```

You could make the task scheduler work at a specific time, but it may not work when your client is turned off.

Comment: Your trick is really awesome. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ivan_Wang suggestions [here](https://pastebin.com/Pv3EsvnC) there is my version of the PowerShell script.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.